# Problem in importing Autograph in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have installed Tensorflow (1.13.0) using conda as follows:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

on my Win64 machine with python 3.6 in my conda environment. I am able to import tensorflow from my Jupyter notebook. In my project, I need to use [AutoGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph). However, when I try to import autograph, then I get this error - ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'

I am able to verify that autograph folder exists in my tensorflow package "..\py36\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph". However, the below code statement gives that Import Error.

```
import tensorflow.python.autograph as ag
```

Complete error trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9224a57db065> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import tensorflow.python.autograph as ag

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\__init__.py in <module>
     33 
     34 # TODO(mdan): Bring only the relevant symbols to the top level.
---> 35 from tensorflow.python.autograph import operators
     36 from tensorflow.python.autograph import utils
     37 from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.converter import ConversionOptions

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\__init__.py in <module>
     38 from __future__ import print_function
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.control_flow import for_stmt
     41 from tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.control_flow import if_stmt
     42 from tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.control_flow import while_stmt

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\control_flow.py in <module>
     19 from __future__ import print_function
     20 
---> 21 from tensorflow.python.autograph.operators import py_builtins
     22 from tensorflow.python.data.ops import dataset_ops
     23 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\operators\py_builtins.py in <module>
     24 import six
     25 
---> 26 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils import py_func
     27 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils import tensors
     28 from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     22 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.misc import alias_tensors
     23 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.py_func import wrap_py_func
---> 24 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.tensor_list import dynamic_list_append
     25 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.testing import fake_tf
     26 from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.type_check import is_tensor

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\utils\tensor_list.py in <module>
     20 
     21 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.ops import list_ops
     23 from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
     24 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\list_ops.py in <module>
     24 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
     25 from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
---> 26 from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_list_ops
     27 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     28 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_list_ops.py in <module>
     21 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops as _ops
     22 from tensorflow.python.framework import op_def_library as _op_def_library
---> 23 from tensorflow.python.util.deprecation import deprecated_endpoints
     24 from tensorflow.python.util import dispatch as _dispatch
     25 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export

ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How should I fix it?